# tf.placeholder inside a class in TF 2.0

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to change a code I have written in TF 1.0 to TF 2.0 and I'm having difficulties with replacing the **tf.placeholder** inside a class function. My code is the following

```
class User:
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,784])
    y_true = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

    W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random.truncated_normal([7840,1], stddev=0.1))
    lambda_W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([7840,1]))    
    W = tf.reshape(W1,[784, 10])

    ylogits = W*x
    y = tf.nn.softmax(ylogits)
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

Is there a way to replace tf.placeholder inside the class to make code running in TF 2.0?

Comment: Depending on what you want to achieve, you don't need placeholders in TF2. A simple fix, to make your code running in a TF2 runtime would be to replace the calls with `tf.compat.v1.placeholder()`. If you want idiomatic TF2 code, you don't need them since you have eager execution. Plain Python Variables will be enough

Comment: Your code is a bit strange in general, all those variables are class variables of `User`, not instance variables (that is, all instances of `User` will share the same variables), is that what you intend to do?

Comment: @jdehesa: not sure if I understand your comment, but what I'm trying to do is to optimize with respect to W1 for each instance (class `User` here refers to a worker in the setting of distributed learning).

Comment: @Chao What I mean is if you do `user1 = User()` and `user2 = User()`, both `user1.W1` and `user2.W1` (and, in general, `User.W1`) will refer to exactly the same object (in this case the same TensorFlow variable), as `W1` is an attribute of the class `User`, not of each instance of the class. I'm not sure if that is what you want or not.

Comment: @jdehesa: Ah, I see, but what I was trying to do is to have `user1.W1` different than `user2.W1`. Do you have an idea how could I do that? Thanks.

Comment: @Chao You should create each of those objects within `__init__`, like `self.W1 = tf.Variable(...)` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I think you intended to have each of those objects created per instance of the class, not one for the whole class as it is now. I also think your product between `W` and `x` was meant to be a matrix product, not an element-wise product, which would not work with the given shapes:

```py
class User:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,784])
        self.y_true = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
        self.W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random.truncated_normal([7840,1], stddev=0.1))
        self.lambda_W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([7840,1]))    
        self.W = tf.reshape(W1,[784, 10])
        self.ylogits = self.x @ self.W
        self.y = tf.nn.softmax(ylogits)
```

To use it in TensorFlow 2.x, you would remove the placeholders and simply perform the operations each time with every new input, for example with a new function `call`:

```py
class User:
    def __init__(self):
        self.W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random.truncated_normal([7840,1], stddev=0.1))
        self.lambda_W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([7840,1]))
        self.W = tf.reshape(W1,[784, 10])

    def call(self, x):
        ylogits = self.x @ self.W
        return tf.nn.softmax(ylogits)
```

You could use this as:

```py
user1 = User()
x = ...  # Get some data
y = user1.call(x)
```

Or if you like to be more "idiomatic", you could use `__call__`:

```py
class User:
    def __init__(self):
        self.W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random.truncated_normal([7840,1], stddev=0.1))
        self.lambda_W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([7840,1]))
        self.W = tf.reshape(W1,[784, 10])

    def __call__(self, x):
        ylogits = x @ W
        return tf.nn.softmax(ylogits)
```

And then you would do:

```py
user1 = User()
x = ...  # Get some data
y = user1(x)
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. One thing I want to ask you as I'm a kind of beginner when it comes to OOP. In your code, why you used `self.ylogits = x @ W` instead of `self.ylogits = self.x @ self.W`.